# Relationship between moment generating functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am trying to work out the moment generating function of a particular probability distribution $\rho(x)$ which is an even function. This means that all the odd moments are zero, so
$$M(s)= \mathbb{E}[e^{sX}] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^{2n} \mu_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
where $\mu_n$ is the nth moment. For my problem, it turns out that working out the above function is difficult and it is easier to work out
$$\tilde{M}(s) = \mathbb{E}[e^{sX^2}] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s^{n} \mu_{2n}}{n!}$$
which can be viewed as the generating function of the even moments. It seems to me that there ought to be a simple relationship between $M$ and $\tilde{M}$. If I have $\tilde{M}$ how can I recover $M$? The reason I would like to have $M$ is because it can (in principle) be inverse Laplace transformed to recover $\rho$, whereas I am not aware of any inversion formula for $\tilde{M}$.

**Update:**

Using the fact that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is also a Gaussian I found that
$$\tilde{M}(-s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi s}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty M(it) e^{-t^2/4s} dt$$
However this is not really what I want since I want to go from $\tilde{M}$ to $M$ not the other way round. Also it is too general since it doesn't rely on $M$ being even.

Comment: Here is a non-explicit formula. Let $f(\xi) = \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{i^n\xi^n}{(2n)!}$, which is an analytic function. Then the operator $L_t:=\sum_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}\partial_x^n$ has fourier symbol $f(t^2\xi)$, so $$M(s) = L_s\tilde M(0) = \int_{\Bbb R} f(s^2\xi) \widehat{\tilde M}(\xi) d\xi=\frac{1}{s^2} \int \hat f\bigg(\frac{x}{s^2}\bigg) \tilde M(x)dx ,$$ where we use Plancherel in last equality, and Fourier inversion formula in the previous one. Now it's just a matter of computing $\hat f$, which idk how to do.

Comment: I think $f(\xi) = \cos \left( (-i \xi)^{1/2} \right)$

Comment: Well no because that function is not entire since $\xi^{1/2}$ requires a branch cut. On the other hand, $f$ **is** entire.

Comment: I think it is still entire. $(\xi^{1/2})^{2n} = \xi^n$, so the branch cut "disappears." Also I should have written $f(\xi) = \cos \left( (-i)^{1/2} \xi^{1/2} \right)$

Comment: Well I still don't think your formula works, but feel free to play around with $f$ and see if you get anything useful.